# ReactDom doesn't show anything and no errors in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am beginner with React and I have a such problem that when I use ReactDom.render there's no output in the browser. I am running the application with

npm start

My previous problem was an error that every time application was run I got:

Target is not a DOM element.

The issue was that index.js was invoked before index.html.

```
 index.js file

 document.addEventListener('game', function() {
 ReactDOM.render(
     "sss",
      document.getElementById('game')
      ); 
 });
```

How should look index.html file to run properly? I have here (index.html) only one line:

```
<div id="game"></div>
```

I was using tutorial where index.html didn't contain any html or head tags. Regards

Comment: You're adding a listener for a `game` *event*, which doesn't exist. If you want to be able to add the script anywhere in the HTML, you need to wrap the `ReactDOM` line in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e1w3vxko/ (note that this applies to *any* JS code that relies on existing HTML elements, and is not React specific)

Comment: should I copy index.css content?

Comment: Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:5136:19)
    at Object.render (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:27309:40)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.

Comment: There's no point in posting the error message unless you also add the code you currently have to your question. And the error is not really React specific, you might want to read all of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: I added the code. Regards

Comment: There's is no `<div id="game"></div>` in your HTML, what exactly is `document.getElementById("game")` supposed to find?

Comment: Thank you I have resolved the issue. There were a name collision.